# java 9 module not found error

Tags: java, maven, java-9

1. C:\csp-config\target               --> has test.jar
2. C:\csp-config\target\classes       --> has module-info.class
3. module-info.java has following code

   ```
   module mymodule {
       requires log4j.api;
   }
   ```

I ran  below command from `C:\csp-config\target` but I am getting log4j.api module not found .

```
jdeps --module-path classes --add-modules  log4j.api   test.jar
```

but I am getting below exception, am I doing something wrong.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.module.FindException: Module
log4j.api not found
```

Comment: What does `jar --file=log4j.api.jar --describe-module` say? It should tell its module name.

Comment: 1. I doubt the module path actually including any module 2. can you also share how is `test.jar` created? Or would be even better if you could shared the complete reproducible steps for the above.

Comment: @AlanBateman when i ran the command i got No module descriptor found . Derived automatic module

Comment: It sounds like you've got the righty module name. Does `java -p classes --list-modules` list the module? If not then the module path you are using is not correct.

Comment: @AlanBateman it does not give the module path , i tried giving module path to actual jar file location also tried giving module-info.class as module path but it did not work , what module path i need to set